# React state is undefined even if on console log is defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<li className="field-title">Role: </li>
{console.log(this.state.userData.roles)}
{this.state.userData.roles.map((role) => {
     return (
       <li>{role.name}</li>
     )
})}
```

When I console log the state of userData it shows the actual array value. But when I am using the mapping it says that:

> this.state.userData.roles is undefined

Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Comment: can you put the result of `console.log` here?

Comment: check for all the console logs you might get a console log for undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code -

```
    { 
       this.state.userData 
       && this.state.userData.roles
       && this.state.userData.roles.length > 0 
       && this.state.userData.roles.map(
         (role) => ... /*rest of your code*/
       ) 
    }
```